# How to login with Linkedin in ASP .Net Mvc 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, linkedin-api

I want to implement linkedin login to my application. I use Owin.Security.Providers, Owin.Security.Providers.Linkedin

My Startup.Auth :

```
app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions()
   {
      ClientId = "my_client_id",
      ClientSecret = "my_client_secret"
   });
```

My Linkedin app :

[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62oO7.png)

[App Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7TDJ.png)

When i click Login with Linkedin and press "Allow" button

[Linkedin Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztmTZ.png)

Program comes to these codes.

```
 // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
            var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginInfo.Email);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToStep(user);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                    ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                    //return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
                    return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
            }
        }
```

But the method i placed below returns null

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

However same codes works well with Facebook login.

I would like to know what you recommend to me